# UINavigationBar appearance different in iOS7 and iOS8

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar

The following code works perfectly on iOS8 but has a strange behavior on iOS7.

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackIndicatorImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icone retour@2x.png"]];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackIndicatorTransitionMaskImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icone retour@2x.png"]];
```

See images below. Any idea ?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Not related to the question but don't use that `@2x`. Just pass the image name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not directly reference the @2x or @3x version of your images, but rather just reference the "base" name and let iOS automatically determine the correct variant for the current device:

```
[UIImage imageNamed:@"icone retour.png"]
```

Regarding the different behavior in iOS7 vs. iOS8 I can only speculate that iOS8 has changed the behavior in `imageNamed:` with regard to the scale of the returned `UIImage` when passing an image with `@2x` or `@3x` in the name. But you should usually not do this anyways.